# Can you set different log levels for different routes in Phoenix?

Tags: logging, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `/ping` route that gets called a lot in production by the load balancer and kubernetes health checks.  I'd like to set the log level of `Plug.Logger` to `:debug` just for that one route.

```
defmodule Web.Endpoint do
  ...
  forward "/ping", Web.HealthCheck
  ...
end

defmodule Web.HealthCheck do
  use Plug.Router

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "ok")
  end
end
```

I've not found a way to modify or remove an existing plug.  I tried adding `plug Plug.Logger, log: :debug` to Web.HealthCheck, but then I just get the route logged twice at different levels

```
[info] GET /ping
[debug] GET /ping
```

I've found a way to disable logging entirely for a specific route by removing `plug Plug.Logger` from `endpoint.ex` and manually adding back as needed https://elixirforum.com/t/disable-logging-on-specific-route/622, but then I have to be careful to remember to make sure logging is enabled for every new route I add, and really I'd prefer just to have the `/ping` route set to debug so it can log in dev as needed, but won't be so spammy in production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a plug that calls `Plug.Logger` with a different level for different paths.

```
defmodule MyApp.Logger do
  def init(_opts), do: {}

  def call(%{path_info: ["ping"]} = conn, _opts) do
    Plug.Logger.call(conn, :error)
  end
  def call(conn, _opts) do
    Plug.Logger.call(conn, :info)
  end
end
```

Now replace `plug Plug.Logger` with `plug MyApp.Logger` in your `Endpoint` module. All requests to `/ping` will now log at `:error` level while everything else will log at `info` level.

Answer (score 8):

In more recent versions of Phoenix it looks like that specific log is now produced by `Phoenix.Logger` in response to telemetry events emitted by `Plug.Telemetry`. Suppressing specific routes can be done in very much the same fashion as with `Plug.Logger`. Either create a separate endpoint / pipeline that does not include telemetry at all, or provide a custom implementation of the plug that alters the log level for certain paths:

```
defmodule MyWeb.Plugs.Telemetry do
  @behaviour Plug

  @impl true
  def init(opts), do: Plug.Telemetry.init(opts)

  @impl true
  def call(%{path_info: ["ping"]} = conn, {start_event, stop_event, opts}) do
    Plug.Telemetry.call(conn, {start_event, stop_event, Keyword.put(opts, :log, :debug)})
  end
  def call(conn, args), do: Plug.Telemetry.call(conn, args)
end
```

and then replace

```
  plug Plug.Telemetry, event_prefix: [:phoenix, :endpoint]
```

with

```
  plug MyWeb.Plugs.Telemetry, event_prefix: [:phoenix, :endpoint]
```

in your `endpoint.ex`.